# Pivot and Non-Pivot Variables

Tags: linear-algebra

Which variables are pivot variables and which ones are non-pivot variables. Also how do I represent this equation in set notation?

$$\begin{pmatrix} 1& 1& 1& -1\\ 0& 1& -1& 1\\ 0& 0& 0& 0 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} x\\ y\\ z\\ w \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 1\\ 1\\ 0 \end{pmatrix} $$

Comment: Do you know the definition of a pivot?

Answer (score 0):

upper left and the entry right and down from upper left are pivots

Comment: How do I represent this function in set notation?